# Measuring outbound requests per second?

Tags: ruby, linux, networking, activeresource

I have a web app that is using
ActiveResource to talk to another server that has a rate limit on the
connection.  I'm curious how I can best monitor that from the host my web app is running on - that is, from a bash prompt on linux from my server, how can I measure the outbound requests per second my machine is making to another?

I'm looking for a linux one-liner that given an interface, a hostname,
and/or some combination thereof, tells me the connection rate I'm
making to that server.  I've gotten close with tools like tc and iftop, but those are reporting the amount of data transferred, not the connections made... so its not quite what I'm looking for.  I'd love to see something
like:

---

$awesometool --host thetargethost.com  --interface eth0  --interval 5

gathering statistics…

Requests per second report for thetargethost.com over interface eth0

avg: 23 req/sec min: 12 req/sec max 39 req/sec

5 samples taken

---

Can anyone point me to one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`tcpdump(8)` can provide something very similar; search for TCP packets with the `SYN` flag set to catch the first packet in the [three-way handshake](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-way_handshake#Connection_establishment) that are destined for your other peer:

```
$ sudo tcpdump -c 10 -i eth0 "tcp[tcpflags] & (tcp-syn) != 0 and dst 192.168.0.1"
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on eth0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 65535 bytes
18:26:24.800308 IP haig.59419 > 192.168.0.1.telnet: Flags [S], seq 3197302320, win 14600, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 19460844 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
...
18:26:27.420132 IP haig.59428 > 192.168.0.1.telnet: Flags [S], seq 1238498237, win 14600, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 19461106 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
10 packets captured
10 packets received by filter
0 packets dropped by kernel
```

You could use `/usr/bin/time` or your shell's `time` built-in, or do some arithmetic with the timestamps in the output, to get your average rate per second. (Use more than ten packets -- this was just for demonstration.)

**Update**

I wrote a little program to run `tcpdump(8)`, count the packets, and report on how many packets were sent within the interval specified:

```
# ./counter --host 192.168.0.1 --interface eth0 --interval 3
2 requests in 3 seconds; average 0.67 req/seq
20 requests in 3 seconds; average 6.67 req/seq
19 requests in 3 seconds; average 6.33 req/seq
19 requests in 3 seconds; average 6.33 req/seq
^C
# ./counter --host 192.168.0.1 --interface eth0 --interval 5
30 requests in 5 seconds; average 6.00 req/seq
20 requests in 5 seconds; average 4.00 req/seq
1176 requests in 5 seconds; average 235.20 req/seq
1414 requests in 5 seconds; average 282.80 req/seq
0 requests in 5 seconds; average 0.00 req/seq
^C
```

Because it asks `tcpdump(8)` to use line-buffered output, I'm a little afraid that it might not scale beyond 200-300 requests per second, at least on my hardware. But without the line-buffered output, `tcpdump(8)` would wait until its output buffer (see `setvbuf(3)` for details) would be full before sending *any* output, causing extremely jittery results.

But if your rate of connections isn't that high, this will probably do what you need. If your rate of connections is higher, then this little hack is probably best ignored -- it strikes me that probably `iptables(8)` can count streams.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <getopt.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

#define CMDLEN 1024
#define TCPDUMPLEN 4096

int show_stats;
long counter;

void alarm_handler(int signum)
{
    show_stats = 1;
}

void install_handler(void)
{
    struct sigaction sa;

    memset(&sa, 0, sizeof(sa));

    sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask);
    sa.sa_handler = &alarm_handler;
    if (sigaction(SIGALRM, &sa, NULL) == -1) {
        perror("Can't install alarm handler");
        exit(1);
    }
}

int count_lines(char *p, int bytes)
{
    int counter = 0;
    char *i;
    for (i=p; i < p+bytes ; i++) {
        if (*i == '\n')
            counter++;
    }
    return counter;
}

int spawn_tcpdump(char *host, char *interface)
{
    int fd[2];
    pid_t child;

    if (pipe(fd) == -1) {
        perror("Can't create pipes");
        exit(1);
    }

    child = fork();

    if (child == -1) {
        perror("Can't fork(2) for tcpdump");
        exit(1);
    }

    if (child == 0) {
        int null;
        int len;
        char syn_and_dst[CMDLEN];

        len = snprintf(syn_and_dst, CMDLEN, "tcp[tcpflags] & (tcp-syn) != 0 and dst %s", host);

        if (len > CMDLEN) {
            perror("host argument too long");
            exit(1);
        }

        /* child writes into pipe */
        close(fd[0]);
        dup2(fd[1], STDOUT_FILENO);

        /* throw away first two lines of tcpdump output */
        null = open("/dev/null", O_WRONLY);

        if (null == -1) {
            perror("Can't open /dev/null");
            exit(1);
        }

        dup2(null, STDERR_FILENO);

        execl("/usr/sbin/tcpdump", "tcpdump", "-l", "-n", "-s 96", "-i", interface, syn_and_dst, (char *) NULL);
        /* can't reach */
        perror("Cannot execute tcpdump");
        exit(1); 
    } else {
        /* parent reads from pipe */
        close(fd[1]);
        return fd[0];
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int tcpdump;
    char *host;
    char *interface;
    long interval;


    while (1) {
        int option_index;
        int c;

        static struct option opts[] = {
            {"host", required_argument, NULL, 'h'},
            {"interface", required_argument, NULL, 'i'},
            {"interval", required_argument, NULL, 'n'},
            {0, 0, 0, 0},
        };

        c = getopt_long(argc, argv, "", opts, &option_index);

        if (c == -1)
            break;

        switch (c) {
            case 'h':
                host = strdup(optarg);
                break;
            case 'i':
                interface = strdup(optarg);
                break;
            case 'n': {
                    char *endptr;
                    interval = strtol(optarg, &endptr, 10);
                    if (!(optarg[0] != '\0' && endptr[0] == '\0')) {
                        fprintf(stderr, "Expected integer; invalid"
                                " input '%s'\n", optarg);
                        exit(1);
                    }
                }
                break;
            default:
                fprintf(stderr, "Option parsing error\n");
                exit(1);
        }

    }

    if (optind < argc) {
        fprintf(stderr, "unexpected arguments: ");
        while (optind < argc) {
            fprintf(stderr, "%s ", argv[optind++]);
        }
        fprintf(stderr, "\n");
    }

    tcpdump = spawn_tcpdump(host, interface);

    install_handler();
    alarm(interval);

    while(1) {
        if (show_stats) {
            printf("%ld requests in %ld seconds; average %2.2f req/seq\n",
                    counter, interval, (double)counter / (double)interval);
            counter = 0;
            show_stats = 0;
            alarm(interval);
        } else {
            char buffer[TCPDUMPLEN];
            int ret;

            memset(buffer, 0, TCPDUMPLEN);
            ret = read(tcpdump, buffer, TCPDUMPLEN);
            if (ret == -1 && errno == EINTR) {
                /* nop */
            } else if (ret == -1) {
                perror("read");
                exit(1);
            } else {
                counter += count_lines(buffer, ret);
            }
        }
    }

    exit(0);
}
```

Comment: Thats an excellent start, but any value for -c would be problematic for times of day where there won't be connections happening.  I'd need it to be able to report '0' connections per second, which could occur during off-hours, but this would hang (waiting) during that time.  Would there be a way to dump tcpdump to a tmp file for a few seconds, then grep to count? For instance, using this solution with Munin, I'd like to get a snapshot once every 5 minutes, and get that in 5 seconds or less.

Comment: Excellent! (my original comment was before your update).  I was hacking something together with perl, defining a shell function, and word count, but your solution is much better.  Thanks for that.